# C#: Question about using generics and picking a random type

Tags: c#

In my game I'm using a powerup system, which basically works like this:

- Enemy gets killed, has random chance to drop powerup box
- Pickup powerup box to get random item

The code for giving the player a random powerup looks like this...

```
Type t = RandomManager.PickFromParams<Type>(typeof(PowerupInvincible), typeof(PowerupDoubleFireRate));
ply.AddPowerup<t>();
```

And the `AddPowerup<>()` method looks like this:

```
public void AddPowerup<T>() where T : PowerupEffect, new()
{
    var powerup = new T();

    powerup.Activate(this);
    powerups.Add(powerup);
}
```

Now, the problem is the `ply.AddPowerup<t>()` line, because it complains that it can't find the type t:

> The type or namespace name 't' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Does anyone know if there's a way to fix this, or if that's not possible, show me a better way to do it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you are not using generics correctly in this instance. I'm assuming `PowerupInvincible`, and `PowerupDoubleFireRate` inherit from some `PowerupBase`:

```
PowerupBase powerUp = RandomManager.PickFromParams<PowerupBase>(typeof(PowerupInvincible), typeof(PowerupDoubleFireRate));

ply.AddPowerup(powerUp);
```

Then the method signature simple need to be:

```
public void AddPowerup(PowerupBase powerup)
{
    powerup.Activate(this);
    powerups.Add(powerup);
}
```

Your random manager would be responsible for choosing one of the parameters, instantiating it, and then returning the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are compile type. `t` is the type at runtime. You will have to invoke the method using reflection or.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/10/10/invoking-generic-methods-with-reflection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like

```
public void AddPowerup(Type powerupType) { 
    if (!powerupType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(PowerupEffect)))
       throw some exception here;
    var powerup = Activator.Create(powerupType);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it - but only with reflection - you have to find the MethodInfo for AddPowerup, make a generic-version from it with type t and then invoke this method for the object ply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass Type arguments at runtime, only compile time. So you would need to hard-code the type rather than using t.

You should probably consider using dependency injection, where AddPowerup() does not actually create the new PowerupEffect, but instead takes a PowerupEffect object through a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The `T` in `<T>` should be the real name of a type, not a variable of type `Type`.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating generic types [is described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ytshk6.aspx):

> > > ```
> > > // Use the typeof operator to create the generic type 
> > > // definition directly. To specify the generic type definition,
> > > // omit the type arguments but retain the comma that separates
> > > // them.
> > > Type d1 = typeof(Dictionary<,>);
> > >
> > > // You can also obtain the generic type definition from a
> > > // constructed class. In this case, the constructed class
> > > // is a dictionary of Example objects, with String keys.
> > > Dictionary<string, Example> d2 = new Dictionary<string, Example>();
> > > // Get a Type object that represents the constructed type,
> > > // and from that get the generic type definition. The 
> > > // variables d1 and d4 contain the same type.
> > > Type d3 = d2.GetType();
> > > Type d4 = d3.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
> > > ```

The good thing about reflection, is that you can forgo the need to code a list of implementors:

```
// TODO proper caching
// TODO proper random generation

var randomType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(MainClass))
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(t => typeof(B).IsAssignableFrom(t))
    .Where(t => !(t.IsAbstract || t.IsInterface))
    .Except(new [] { typeof(PowerupBase) })
    .OrderBy (t => new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond).Next())
    .First();

Activator.CreateInstance(x);
```

Comment: Added reflection based dynamic random factory sample